# Securing front-end JS app and Rails API communication with SSL/TLS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, rest, ssl, backbone.js

I have a Rails JSON API with token based authentication, and a static front-end client using Backbone.js (which is served from a different Rails server).

I am thinking of how to secure the communication between the front-end and the API, since plain text credentials will be sent during signup/login from the browser forms, and the auth token is sent in the Authorization header on every request.

I'm thinking of forcing SSL on the Rails API server (with nginx or Puma/Passenger config).

Is my understanding correct, that as long as the call is made from the browser front-end app via HTTPS, the connection from the browser running the JS code to the Rails API will be encrypted?

Do I need a signed cert from an authority, or a self-signed one would suffice? Since the actual front-end code is served from a different server than the API (most likely not using HTTPS) and only the REST calls from JS code will be (supposedly) secured, can I possibly get the warm and fuzzy URL bar lock in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You a right when you establish an https connection the traffic is encrypted in both ways.
2. If you use a self signed certificate or one that is signed by verisign for example relies on your purpose and usage of the API.

Both are effective against criminals but the self signed will cause problems if the API is called by the browser itself. For example you cant tell jQuery to establish a ssl connection that is based on a self signed certificate so it wont work. If you only use the API serverside with your own library it realies on the possibility of the library to deactivate Certificate verification.

From the security look a self signed certificate migth even be more secure because only you own the private key. When you receive a certificate form an authoritey they will keep a copy of the private key. So the government can go to the authority and force them to give the key to them.

// If you want to force using ssl even on the "normal" page you can do this using redirects like described here: https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx

Comment: Thanks. I am planning to call from the browser indeed using CORS with an explicitly set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but I didn't think about the self-signed certificate warning - I guess will have to get a signed one after all. So as long as the certificate is signed and the endpoint is HTTPS I should get an encrypted AJAX call from a page server with non-SSL HTTP?

Comment: If the url you provide starts with `https://` it will be encrypted aslong the server is configured to do so. If you want to really verify it use wireshark to capture the traffic your application generates.

Comment: But in this case, the page itself is not served with https so no chance of getting the lock displayed, right?

Comment: The Page itselve is served with https when you connect to it using a `https` link and the server is configured to use ssl. What you can do is force using ssl. => http://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx